# Exchange server 2013 on windows server 2012r2

Tags: exchange-server

[I installed exchange server 2013 on server 2012r2 .... after login Exchange Administrative center got this error "500 Unexpected Error" ] Then what will i do?

[After login Exchange Administrative center got this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOd6X.png)

Comment: There should be an error in the server logs. Posting that might get you more help.

Answer (score 0):

You may find with 2013 and exchange 2016 that if your using chrome or firefox that often now you'll get hit with a 500 error because out of the box exchange is supporting encryption cyphers that are no longer supported. It would be nice for MS to identify such things up front but the do not.
A recommendation is to download IISCrypto 2 tool which identifies crpto levels on your machine. Run the best practices template and then reboot your machine.

Often another possibility is the ssl certificate assigned in IIS to both the front and backend systems. By Default it should assign a exchange self signed cert but sometimes it may get left blank and needs to be assigned.

Those are two common 500 errors.